# Использование класса Intent для обращения к системным приложениям

Tags: android

С помощью intent можно позвонить, отправить смс, открыть клиент для отправки email и т.п. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие intent и как их использовать, чтобы открыть изображение, аудио или видео файл в стандартном для этого приложении (или выбрав в списке установленных для этого), имея путь к файлу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё так же просто как и со звонками:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("путь к файлу"), "тип файла");
startActivity(intent);
```

Где в типе файла указывает то, что вы хотите открыть. Это могут быть изображения (**"image/*"**), видео (**"video/*"**) или аудио (**"audio/*"**). Это так называемые типы медиа фалов. Полный их список можно посмотреть [**здесь**](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types).

Comment: Можете подсказать - почему-то видео открывается нормально с помощью приведенного выше кода, а вот изображение, когда открываю, например, галерею - там черный экран, ошибки не пишет, но изображение не показывает, хотя путь правильный.

Comment: @Asy, попробуйте просмотреть LogCat во время запуска Интента. Должно выскочить исключение.

Comment: Начало лога:
    05-31 00:15:16.571: E/AndroidRuntime(368): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-31 00:15:16.571: E/AndroidRuntime(368): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ViewImage}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-31 00:15:16.571: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)...
    Вроде как uri пустой, но я туда точно правильный путь вставляю.

Answer (score 1):

```
Я использую такой вариант открытия файлов:

 String mime = gi.get_mime_by_filename(path to file);
                                Intent intent1 = new Intent();
                                intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                intent1.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                intent1.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(aDirectory
                                    .getAbsolutePath())), mime);

                            try {
                                startActivity(intent1);
                            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Couldn't open: unknown file type",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            public String get_mime_by_filename(String filename){
                  String ext;
                  String type;

                  int lastdot = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
                  if(lastdot > 0){
                    ext = filename.substring(lastdot + 1);
                    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                    type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
                    if(type != null) {
                      return type;
                    }
                  }
                  return "application/octet-stream";
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Asy](/users/12188/asy) вопрос не совсем корректный.

Для примера, чтобы была понятна моя мысль, возьмите Windows и попробуйте открыть в Проводнике любой файл, скажем с расширением `.zip`. Если у вас зарегистрирована программа обработчик (аналог Intent) `.zip` то у вас запустится эта программа: у меня например запускается 7-zip, у кого-то Winzip, у кого-то WinRAR и т.д. То же самое и с `Intent`'ами, только в Android эта концепция гораздо более глубже проработана чем в Windows.

Вы заранее не знаете какие есть Intent'ы отрабатывающие то или иное действие в данном устройстве. Их может быть много, или один или вообще ни одного. Поэтому вопрос о системном Intent'е некорректен.

Вы можете вывести список приложений отрабатывающих тот или иной `Intent`, делается это через `PackageManager.queryIntentActivities()` - на вход ему подается подготовленный `Intent` (например как в посте [@imholynx](/users/6787/imholynx))

Comment: Конечно соглашусь, с "системным приложением" - это я загнула. А вообще имела в виду примерно то, что Вы написали, спасибо.